# Enable syntax highlighting in TeXlipse for other file extensions

Tags: texlipse

Since I put my tikzpictures in external files with .tikz as extension for use with tikz-scale, syntax highlighting in texlipse wont work for them. Is there a way to enable it?

[In this thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/texlipse/discussion/451977/thread/73b4fe0c/) it was mentioned in 2007 to be included as an option in the next release, however, I cannot find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know the question is old but I came across it while searching the answer.

Simply go to

`Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> General -> Content Types -> Text -> Latex File`

and add the extension you want like `*.tikz` and reopen the file.

Comment: Wow, perfect! That is great! And today I was just wondering about it because I started to work on some graphics again :)